# Please review design for a wifi controllable led driver

Tags: mosfet, esp8266

I'm trying to dabble a bit in circuit design. As a starting project, I've taken it upon myself to create little wifi controllable led drivers for a couple of (very cheap) light strings I own. The idea is simple: have a power source (usb charger), hook it up with a DC jack to the circuit, power an ESP-01, have the ESP-01 control a mosfet which allows a current through the leds. I've mapped this circuit out in Kicad. I've built a variation of it in real life, and that currently works well enough, but I'd like some pointers about what I designed, so I can learn from it :)

[image: Current state of the circuit]

Update:

I've switched the mosfet out for a BS170, and added an output capacitor as specified in the datasheet.

[image: After first revision]

Comment: @rdtsc'a advice is all good. || Better than 3V3 drive for the LEDs you can use 5V directly and series resistors (or a single common series  resistor if you must - which is inferior). Rs = V/I = (5V - Vf_LED) / I_LED.  | Using 5V gives you some "headroom" to design the current. | There are a vast number of FETs suited to this task. The 2N7000 is unsuited  for the reasons rdtsc have.

Comment: The nice thing about the 2N7000 is it's small size, low cost, and low \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ of 3v, making it ideal for small 5v logic-driven tasks. But it's really meant for small-signal work and not driving loads like LED's. If you search a bit, there are more MOSFETs available with low gate threshold voltages, better current-carrying ability, lower \$R_{DS(ON)}\$, etc.

Comment: Where are your decoupling capacitors?

Comment: I think I left them in my other jacket :D by decoupling capacitor you mean a cap in parallel with the leds, right?

Comment: @DaanMeijer: When posting questions, please Keep in mind, if they can be of use not only for you but for all future visitors of this Q&A site. A good posts's title always can e.g. be formulated with a "?" at the end, because it is specific, so a visitor can easy decide, if it is of interest by browsing through the list or search result. Your post might yield good results for you but not for others, so next time try to break it down to several more specific problems and questions in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Three things,

- The [2N7000](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N7000-D.PDF) is only good for 200mA (0.2A) so is probably getting hot. The Vgs(th) or voltage gate-to-source threshold, is a maximum of 3.0v for this device. That means, putting 3.0 volts on the gate may (at least) allow 1mA to flow from the drain. 3.3v might allow only 50mA to flow (it would have to be measured and would vary from MOSFET to MOSFET). It *can* take a gate voltage of +/-20v however, so the higher this goes, the more conductive it will become. If you could put 5v on the gate, even better. Careful handling these out of circuit though; static electricity can easily zap the sensitive gate lead and render them useless.
- If the 3.3v rail measures low (such as 3.1v) consider using two [AMS1117](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf)'s and power the ESP from a dedicated one. It will help to place a "decoupling capacitor" right next to the AMS1117's output lead. Always read the component datasheets! *"The circuit design used in the AMS1117 series requires the use of an output capacitor as part of the device frequency compensation. The addition of 22µF solid tantalum on the output will ensure stability for all operating conditions."*
- Some white LEDs may have a forward voltage of near 3.2v, so they happily glow brightly when powered from 3.3v. But LEDs are *diodes*, which means that after the voltage point where they start glowing is passed, they draw exponentially more current per voltage increase. As such, they cannot safely be powered from a constant voltage supply alone. A series resistor is needed for each LED such that if the voltage were to rise, the resistor would safely dissipate the extra power. There are dozens of posts here about LEDs and calculating resistor values.

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointers! One thing I'm not clear about: how do you select parts, especially for working with Kicad? I found STD2NC45-1 for instance (what would you say about using that mosfet? Or is BS170-D27Z better in your opinion?) but Kicad has no symbol for that.

Comment: Quite welcome. Well, KiCAD is sort-of it's own universe, and so are DigiKey, Mouser, Farnell, etc. It would be *wonderful* if everyone could agree on parts, but sadly this will never happen. There are far too many different components now, from vendors all across the world, with an ever-increasing number of new parts (and packages) emerging and old parts fading away. The usual discourse is to first *find* a valid part for sale, then make KiCAD represent this in your schematic properly. The BS170 is very similar to the 2N7000 so will have nearly identical performance.

Comment: The [STD2NC45](https://datasheet.octopart.com/STD2NC45-1-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-7591303.pdf), while far superior in almost every way, has a \$V_{GS(th)}\$ of max 3.7v, which means it probably won't even "turn on" noticeably at 3.3v.  You should research how to use a transistor and resistor to drive the gate pin from 0v to 5v, that will definitely turn it on well. Time for some research and experimentation.